# Java, Web Pages, Ads and Revenue - Ethics

Tags: java, ads

I have a small Java program which hits a URL of a website I like and grabs an image so I can view it all on its own without the rest of the site.

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://example.com/");
URLConnection conn = myURL.openConnection();
```

I parse the HTML on the page, find the image, and display it in a window.

Now, the site in question gets it's revenue from Ads on the page.

My question is, does the site still make any money when I "visit" it with Java rather than visiting it in my browser? Or am I bypassing the system and the site loses money?

Assuming the site ads do not load, is there a way to "load" them so that the site can make money off my visit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about ethics, not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just connecting via Java and fetching the image will not load the ads, which are almost certainly loaded by JavaScript. Doing a GET on the page source will probably not even fetch the JavaScript files, let alone execute them.

Comment: right, you fetch only the html code of the page, nothing else will be loaded. until your order it.

Comment: so to be clear, the site is losing money?

Comment: @EliteOctagon The site is not gaining any ad impressions from you visiting it via Java, so they are not making money. I suppose you could say they are losing out on the fraction of a cent that they would get if you visited the site through a browser and were delivered an ad.

Comment: To be clear, yes, the site is losing out.  And if you ran the javascript then the advertizer would be losing out ... 'cos he'd be getting "page views" when no real person actually saw the adverts on the site's page.

Comment: Thanks for the info, is there a way around this so that the site would actually make money?

Comment: @EliteOctagon - Not without (potentially) getting >>them<< into trouble with the advertizers / advert brokers, due to generating false pageviews.

Comment: You could use something like Selenium to actually load the page in a real browser, and extract the image using that. This would result in the ad impression, but then you're back to the ethics question, as no human being will actually see the ad. :)

Answer (score 1):

The only ethical solution to this is:

1. Read and respect the website's terms of use.
2. Respect what the robots.txt file says.
3. If you are still concerned, reach out to them and ask permission for what you are doing.

Any purely technical solution to this is likely to short-change the website owner, the ad broker, or the business that is paying for the advertisements.